# Why do 2 equivalent variables not equal each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

So I have the following code where chalnum (short for challenge number) is a randomly generated number. You have to try to get that number through a sequence of inputs (finalnum2). But for some reason, it always thinks the numbers aren't equal even when they are.

```
   chal = input('Would you like a challenge number? (y/n) ')
   if 'ye' in chal or chal == 'y':
       str = 'Try to get %s \n'
       chalnum = round(uniform(5, 5000))
       print(str % colored(chalnum, attrs=['underline']))
   else:
       chalnum = 0
       print('\n')
```

some more code where you make your number, then:

```
finalnum2 = round(num/ex_num2)
    (chalnum, finalnum2)
    if finalnum2 == chalnum:
        chalcomp = (colored('Congrats! You completed the challenge!', 'green'))
        for i in range(chalcomp):
            print(chalcomp[i], sep='', end='', flush=True); sleep(0.14)
    elif chalnum == 0:
        pass
    elif finalnum2 > chalnum or finalnum2 < chalnum:
        chalfail = (colored('Oh no! It looks like you failed the challenge!', 'red'))
        for i in range(chalfail):
            print(chalfail[i], sep='', end='', flush=True); sleep(0.14)
    else:
        raise Exception
```

Please keep in mind that I am a beginner so if it's a stupid mistake please don't be harsh.

Comment: "it always thinks the numbers aren't equal even when they are" I don't think the numbers should ever be equal. Please try to convince me of a case where they should be, and then you should realize the problem. I especially have no idea how "some more code where you make your number" should cause the numbers to be equal, because I can't even see that code, and I'm not even sure *which numbers you're talking about*.

Comment: Basically: please read [ask] and try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We *do* need the stuff about how you get the values you compare; we *don't* need the stuff about how you print coloured text.

Answer (score 0):

possible that they both in different types like 24!='24'
Use typecasting and convert into say

```
if int(finalnum2) == int(chalnum):
```

Comparison would go well in this case.